# Increment a variable in LESS css

Tags: css, less

How Can I increment a variable in LESS css?

Here is the example..

```
@counter: 1;
.someSelector("nameOfClass", @counter);
@counter: @counter + 1;
.someSelector("nameOfClass", @counter);
```

The above code snippet will cause this "Syntax Error"

```
SyntaxError: Recursive variable definition for @counter
```

Is there a work around for this error? For example is there a notation like @counter++ ?

Thanks..

Comment: Isn't this is just a minified duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199298?

Comment: @seven-phases-max: probably (suspiciously similar both in question and timing).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Not Strictly Possible

See [the documentation on LESS variables](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading). Essentially, LESS variables are constants in the scope of their creation. They are lazy loaded, and cannot be "changed" in that way. The very last definition will be the one used for all in that scope. In your case an error will occur, because variables cannot reference themselves.

Consider this example:

```less
@counter: 1;
.someSelector("nameOfClass", @counter);
@counter: 2;
.someSelector("nameOfClass1", @counter);

.someSelector(@name; @count) {
  @className: ~"@{name}";
  .@{className} {
  test: @count;
  }
}
```

The output will be `2` for both:

```
.nameOfClass {
  test: 2;
}
.nameOfClass1 {
  test: 2;
}
```

This is because LESS defines the `@counter` with the last definition of the variable in that scope. It does not pay attention to the *order* of the calls using `@counter`, but rather acts much like CSS and takes the "cascade" of the variable into consideration.

For further discussion of this in LESS, you might track discussion that occurs on [this LESS feature request](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1545).

### Solution is in Recursive Call Setter for the Local Variable

Seven-phases-max [linked](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/7647414) to what he believes to be a bug in LESS, but I don't think it is. Rather, it appears to me to be a creative use of recursive resetting of the counter to get the effect desired. This allows for you to achieve what you desire like so (using my example code):

```less
// counter

.init() {
  .inc-impl(1); // set initial value
} .init();

.inc-impl(@new) {
  .redefine() {
    @counter: @new;
  }
}

.someSelector(@name) {
  .redefine(); // this sets the value of counter for this call only
  .inc-impl((@counter + 1)); // this sets the value of counter for the next call
  @className: ~"@{name}";
  .@{className} {
    test: @counter;
  }
}

.someSelector("nameOfClass");
.someSelector("nameOfClass1");
```

Here is the CSS output:

```
.nameOfClass {
  test: 1;
}
.nameOfClass1 {
  test: 2;
}
```

**NOTE:** I believe you are not strictly changing a global value here, but rather setting a new local value with each call to `.someSelector`. Whether this is based on buggy behavior or not is questionable, but if so, this solution may disappear in the future. 
For further comments of the limitations of this method, [see the discussion here](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1678).

Comment: Btw. I've just remembered that there's a LESS bug/issue that can be abused to emulate such counter and variable redefinition. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/7647414). But this no more than just a curious hack of course. I hope the issue will be fixed eventually.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: I disagree that it is a bug in [your gist](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/7647414). There is a single global scoped mixin `.inc()` defined, which recursively sets a local variable of `@counter` on each call (it is not actually changing a global counter variable). So in essence it is tracking a continuous count, but serving up the variable locally, which is exactly what is needed for a solution here. I've adapted both this code and [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199298/sprites-less-css-variable-increment-issue) to work utilizing this.

Comment: Either way, even if this considered to be an issue it's almost impossible to fix without major compiler refactoring so this behavior barely changes any time soon so I think it's pretty much safe to use. If no other less hackish solution exists of course.

Comment: Btw. just in case also notice that you don't have to change .inc() itself to use new counter value. See [another variant](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/7649229), this way the implementation can even be put into separate less file. I also put some comments there on the issues involved (it seems to be even more complected than I wrote above).

Comment: Btw. this trick won't probably work in Less 1.7.0 (it turned out this is based on the [#1291](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1291) issue which was fixed recently). Or maybe it will, I'm not sure needs more tests...

Comment: - update: It will work partially. Counter increases only when updated within global scope.