# Auto-generate LESS styles for sprite icons

Tags: less, auto-generate

I have icon sprites image with each icon in a 20 by 20 pixel area. Each icon has several variants (black, colour, white small etc.). And have a significant amount of them. Instead of writing styles for each individual icon I'd rather just provide their names in my LESS file and let the processor generate styles for them.

This is what I came up with but it doesn't seem to work.

```
@icons: upvote,downvote,comment,new,notify,search,popup,eye,cross;

@array: ~`(function(i){ return (i + "").replace(/[\[\] ]/gi, "").split(","); })("@{icons}")`;
@count: ~`(function(i){ return i.split(",").length; })("@{icons}")`;

.iconize (@c) when (@c < @count) {
    @val: ~`(function(a){ return a.replace(" ","").split(",")[0]; })("@{array}")`;
    @array: ~`(function(a){ a = a.replace(" ","").split(","); a.splice(0, 1); return a; })("@{array}")`;

    &.@{val} { background-position: (-20px * @c) 0; }
    &.color.@{val} { background-position: (-20px * @c) -20px; }
    &.white.@{val} { background-position: (-20px * @c) -40px; }

    .iconize(@c + 1);
}

.iconize(@c) when (@c = @count) {}

.iconize(0);
```

The only thing I'd like to edit is the `@icons` variable where I just enter their names. And I'm using Web Essentials addin for Visual Studio 2013 to automatically process my LESS file on file save.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure LESS (assuming you're using Web Essentials 2013 which uses LESS 1.5.x):

```
@icons: upvote, downvote, comment, new, notify, search, popup, eye, cross;

.iconize();
.iconize(@i: length(@icons)) when (@i > 0) {
    .iconize((@i - 1)); 

    @value: extract(@icons, @i); // LESS arrays are 1-based
    .@{value}       {background-position: (-20px * (@i - 1)) 0}
    .color.@{value} {background-position: (-20px * (@i - 1)) -20px}
    .white.@{value} {background-position: (-20px * (@i - 1)) -40px}
}
```

I removed `&` from selector names since it has no effect when you generate these classes in the global scope (but put it back if you actually need `.iconize` to be nested in another ruleset). It is also possible to calculate array length in earlier LESS versions (that have no `length` function) w/o any javascript, but I don't list this method here since it's quite scary (and you don't need it anyway).

---

Your javascript based loop is in fact less or more correct but the problem is all values returned by LESS inline javascript are of so-called "anonymous value" type and not a numbers so that `when (@c < @count)` condition is always true and the loop becomes infinite. (basically the condition is expanded exactly as `when (0 < ~'9')` ... `when (9 < ~'9')` = true etc.)

Comment: Yes my classes are nested within so I need `&`. And thanks for this solution as it work perfectly as I want it. I find it strange though that official LESS.org documentation doesn't talk anything about `length` or `extract` functions. Is there a better documentation site maybe?

Comment: Yes, better docs are in the pipeline: https://github.com/less/less-docs (up-to-date [functions ref](https://github.com/less/less-docs/tree/master/content/functions))

Comment: @Robert I updated the example with a bit smarter `.iconize` arg handling so that you don't have to repeat `length(@icons)` each time `.iconize` used.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm calling it only once anyway. There was something else that I changed though: background position calculations, as `@i` goes between `1` and `length(@icons)`. I subtracted 1 from it so offsets are correct.

Comment: Ah, right I did miss that 0-based vs. 1-based part... So I'll update the example with it too...

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the version of LESS you use. Different versions of LESS handle array like structures and their length different.

Since LESS 1.5 you can define an array with quotes, like:

`@array: "value1","value2";` and calculate its length with `length(@array)`.

For example see also:
[Sprites LESS CSS Variable increment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199298/sprites-less-css-variable-increment-issue/20200431)

With LESS 1.5 your code ends in an endless loop: "SyntaxError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in"