# Less: add a number to string

Tags: less

I need to extract part of a string and add a number to it. Here is my code:

```
.sprite-position-offset(@sprite; @offset-x; @offset-y) {
  @sprite-offset-x: ~`"@{sprite}".split(', ')[2]` + @offset-x;
  @sprite-offset-y: ~`"@{sprite}".split(', ')[3]` + @offset-y;
  background-position: @sprite-offset-x  @sprite-offset-y;
}
```

The result of

```
~`"@{sprite}".split(', ')[2]`
```

is `100px`, for example.

In the example above i get `Unrecognised input in file` error.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Split would return a string so you would probably have to convert that to integer prior to doing arithmetic operations. I guess you are probably looking for something like [this](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/yKvut) but I think even this approach is not the best option.

Comment: [This](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/wjKGC) is a simpler and better option using the built-in extract function.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/20605832

Comment: @Harry, thank you so much. http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/wjKGC works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options to achieve this. The first option below is the simpler and better one because it uses built-in `extract` function.

**Option 1:**

```
.sprite-position-offset(@offset-x; @offset-y; @sprite...) { /* the mixin */
    @sprite-offset-x: extract(@sprite,3) + @offset-x; /* calculate x offset */
    @sprite-offset-y: extract(@sprite,4) + @offset-y; /* calculate y offset */
    @sprite-url: extract(@sprite,1); /* extract the url of the image */
    background: url(@sprite-url);
    background-position: @sprite-offset-x @sprite-offset-y;
}

a{ /* any selector within which you want to call the mixin */
    .sprite-position-offset(1px,1px,"/path/to/image.jpg",b,100px,100px);
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. We are using a mixin with the first two paramters as the offset in `x` and offset in `y`.
2. `...` indicates that the mixin can have variable number of arguments. In this case all the parameters that are passed to the mixin starting from the third would be assigned to the `@sprite` variable.
3. `extract(@sprite,3)` - This extracts the third value from the `@sprite` parameter (which is 100px). After extraction, we add the offset value from the mixin call to it.
4. **Note:** The `...` and `extract` is not really required if we pass them as separate parameters to the mixin (like `@offset-x; @offset-y; @sprite; @x; @y`.

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/wjKGC)

---

**Option 2:** (complex and not recommended)

```
.sprite-position-offset(@sprite; @offset-x; @offset-y) {
  @temp: ~"@{sprite}";
  @sprite-offset-x: ~`parseInt("@{temp}".split(', ')[2],10) + @{offset-x}`;
  @sprite-offset-y: ~`parseInt("@{temp}".split(', ')[3],10) + @{offset-y}`;
  background-position: unit(@sprite-offset-x,px)  unit(@sprite-offset-y,px);
}

a{
  .sprite-position-offset("/path/to/image.jpg, b, 100, 100",1,1);
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. The output of the `split` function is a string and hence it would have to be converted to a number before we can do arithmetic operations on it. This can be done using the `parseInt(string, radix)` function.
2. The `unit(number,px)` appends the unit (`px`) to the calculated numeric value.

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/yKvut)

---

**Additional Information:** You can also have a look at the answer posted by [seven-phases-max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2712740/seven-phases-max) in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605832/auto-generate-less-styles-for-sprite-icons) for a different approach towards generation of styles for sprite icons. It uses a loop and a bit more of arithmetic operations to generate the styles and can be very useful when writing styles for multiple such sprite icons.